# Google analytics event tracking on the server side

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm trying  to track my events from server side and based on documentation it is possible. I found an example with node.js ([link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/integrating-with-analytics)) but it is not working for me as well curl calls (response is 200 but the called event is not visible in the report or real time data).

When I'm using webbrowser url link with the same payload data "https://google-analytic.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-xxxxxxxx-x&cid=cid555&ec=test&ea=test&el=test&ev=10  everything is ok.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Hi Szymon, your question seems to be lacking any sort of code or explanation of what you have tried. Could you add a snippet of code and the result? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Eugenio. I tried to track events from server side(i.e. node.js) into google analytics. I used example as is described in the link and send some event to my account. Server receives response ok from GA but the event was not tracked on my account. The same data used as url link working fine, Thanks